Seeking an Efficient Perfect Hashing Function integer keys running on a small MCU?
I am developing a CANopen slave stack on a 200 MHz microcontroller and require a highly efficient lookup method to match a 16-bit object index (e.g., 0x603d) with a table index where the objects are stored. The expected range for used objects is between 200 and 400.
Although I considered using a perfect hashing function with a 16-bit table, the fill factor for this hash map would be only 400 / (2**16 - 1) * 100, or approximately 0.6%. I believe my challenge lies in finding a code generator for a perfect hashing function for 16-bit integers. I've explored options like MPHF, BBHash, gperf, and CMPH. Most of these either work primarily with strings or they offer O(1) lookup time but involve complex algorithms that are not suitable for my embedded application.
As an alternative, I experimented with a brute force technique using two different typical xor/shift hashing functions. By iterating over the seed, I search for a minimal collision ratio to then build an open addressing hash map table.
Here is a snippet of the Python code I used:
def hash32(key, seed):
    h = seed
    h ^= ((h << 7) ^ key * (h >> 3) ^ (~((h << 11) + (key ^ (h >> 5))))) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    h = (~h + (h << 15)) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    h ^= (h >> 11) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    h = ((h + (h << 3)) + (h << 8)) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    h ^= (h >> 13) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    h = ((h + (h << 2)) + (h << 4)) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    h ^= (h >> 17) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    h = (h + (h << 15)) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    return h

def fatou(key, seed=0):
    return ((key ^ seed) * 0x45d9f3b) & 0xFFFFFFFF

# Some data
data = [4096, 4097, 4098, 4099, 5120, 5121, 5122, 5123, 5632, 5633, 5634, 5635,
        6147, 8710, 8711, 8712, 4112, 4113, 8720, 8721, 8723, 16400, 16401, 4119,
        4120, 4121, 8728, 8729, 16403, 16404, 16405, 16406, 8736, 8737, 8738, 8741,
        4137, 9474, 25858, 9475, 24639, 24640, 24641, 24666, 16402, 24669, 24672,
        24673, 24674, 24676, 24677, 24678, 24679, 24680, 24683, 24684, 24685, 24686,
        24687, 24688, 24689, 24690, 24691, 24692, 24693, 24694, 24695, 24696, 24697,
        24698, 24700, 24701, 24702, 24703, 24704, 20480, 24705, 24707, 24708, 24709,
        20481, 24711, 24719, 24721, 24722, 24728, 24729, 24730, 24744, 24745, 24746,
        24747, 6144, 24773, 6145, 24774, 6146, 6656, 6657, 6658, 6659, 24803, 24818,
        24824, 24831, 8448, 8449, 8450, 8451, 8960, 8961, 8962, 8963, 9472, 8964,
        9473, 8965, 8966, 9476, 9477, 8704, 8705, 8706, 8707, 9216, 8708, 9217,
        9728, 9220, 9729, 9221, 8713, 9222, 9223, 9224, 8722, 12288, 26622]


def countCollisions(data, seed, map_size, hf):
    """ Count collisions in a hash map for a given hash function and seed"""
    max_collisions = 0
    collisions = 0

    m = [0] * map_size
    for key in data:
        m[hf(key, seed) % map_size] += 1

    for i in range(map_size):
        max_collisions = m[i] if m[i] > max_collisions else max_collisions
        collisions += m[i] - 1 if m[i] > 1 else 0

    return collisions, max_collisions


def findBestSeed(data, mapsize, hh):
    """ Find the best seed for a given hash function and data"""
    print("Finding best seed...")
    m = len(data)
    s = 0
    for i in range(0xffff):
        c, cc = countCollisions(data, i, mapsize, hh)
        if c < m:
            m = c
            s = i
            print(f"   Found seed {s} with {m} collisions, worse case with a maximum of {cc} elements per bucket")
        if c == 0:
            break
    return s, m


def buildOpenAdressingMap(data, seed, mapsize, hh):
    """ Build an open addressing hash map for a given hash function and seed"""
    d = [None] * mapsize
    for key in data:
        index = hh(key, seed) % mapsize
        while d[index] is not None:
            index += 1
        d[index] = key
    return d

fill_factor = 0.5
map_size = int(len(data) / fill_factor)
hfunc = fatou

seed, collisions = findBestSeed(data, map_size, hfunc)
print(f"Best seed {seed} with {collisions} collisions")
hm = buildOpenAdressingMap(data, seed, map_size, hfunc)

The output is:
Finding best seed...
   Found seed 0 with 14 collisions, worse case with a maximum of 2 elements per bucket
   Found seed 4 with 12 collisions, worse case with a maximum of 2 elements per bucket
   Found seed 7 with 11 collisions, worse case with a maximum of 2 elements per bucket
   Found seed 768 with 8 collisions, worse case with a maximum of 2 elements per bucket
   Found seed 4316 with 7 collisions, worse case with a maximum of 2 elements per bucket
   Found seed 16428 with 6 collisions, worse case with a maximum of 2 elements per bucket
   Found seed 16430 with 4 collisions, worse case with a maximum of 2 elements per bucket
   Found seed 16431 with 3 collisions, worse case with a maximum of 2 elements per bucket
Best seed 16431 with 3 collisions

Interestingly, the hash32 function is less efficient than the fatou function when translated into ARM 32-bit assembly, which consists of 19 instructions versus just 5 for fatou.
Given that even with a fill factor of 0.5, I still encounter three collisions, I am seeking a hashing function that could potentially achieve a 1.0 fill factor with zero collisions. Ideally, the hashing function should be executable in fewer than ten assembly instructions.
Fatou's assembly:
    eors    r0, r0, r1
    movw    r3, #40763
    movt    r3, 1117
    mul     r0, r3, r0
    bx      lr

This answer looks interesting, but I don't really understand how I can store data in my buckets. I tried to build something (with great help of ChatGPT) but it doesn't give me unique buckets indices.
import sys
import random
from collections import defaultdict


def generate_constants():
    return random.randint(1, sys.maxsize), random.randint(1, sys.maxsize)


class HashTable:
    def __init__(self, list_of_keys, retry_limit=10):
        self.m = len(list_of_keys)  # Define table size based on the number of keys
        attempt = 0
        while attempt < retry_limit:
            self.C1, self.C2 = generate_constants()
            self.graph, self.edges = self.create_graph(list_of_keys)
            if not self.is_cyclic(self.graph):
                self.setup_hash_table(self.edges)
                return
            attempt += 1
        raise Exception("Failed to create an acyclic graph after several attempts.")

    def setup_hash_table(self, edges):
        table1 = [None] * self.m
        table2 = [None] * self.m
        for key, (index1, index2) in edges.items():
            if table1[index1] is None and table2[index2] is None:
                assign_value = random.randint(0, 100)
                table1[index1] = assign_value
                table2[index2] = key - assign_value
            elif table1[index1] is not None:
                table2[index2] = key - table1[index1]
            elif table2[index2] is not None:
                table1[index1] = key - table2[index2]
        self.table1 = table1
        self.table2 = table2


    def h1(self, key):
        return ((key * self.C1) + (self.C1 >> 5)) % self.m


    def h2(self, key):
        return ((key * self.C2) + (self.C2 >> 5)) % self.m


    def __call__(self, key):
        return self.table1[self.h1(key)] + self.table2[self.h2(key)]


    def create_graph(self, list_of_keys):
        graph = defaultdict(list)
        edges = {}
        for key in list_of_keys:
            index1 = self.h1(key)
            index2 = self.h2(key)
            graph[index1].append(index2)
            graph[index2].append(index1)
            edges[key] = (index1, index2)
        return graph, edges


    def is_cyclic(self, graph):
        visited = [False] * self.m
        rec_stack = [False] * self.m

        def dfs(node, parent):
            visited[node] = True
            rec_stack[node] = True
            for neighbor in graph[node]:
                if not visited[neighbor]:
                    if dfs(neighbor, node):
                        return True
                elif rec_stack[neighbor] and neighbor != parent:
                    return True
            rec_stack[node] = False
            return False

        for i in range(self.m):
            if not visited[i]:
                if dfs(i, -1):
                    print("Cycle detected involving node", i)
                    return True
        return False

    
keys = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
hf = HashTable(keys)

for key in keys:
     print(key, hf(key))

Is there a different approach, a parametric hashing function suitable for brute force exploration to achieve zero collisions and a 100% fill factor? What would you recommend for this application?

Are your keys 16-bit, or 24-bit?  Your text contradicts itself... But either way, you can treat the key as a string (of 2 or 3 bytes, respectively), and use any of the existing perfect hash generators on it.

@jasonharper Unfortunately with gperf, the input should be ascii. As my keys converted in bytes could be 0x00 or \n, gperf complains.

Looks like gperf has a -l option for doing binary instead of string comparisons.  You'd have to write non-ASCII bytes in the input file in the form of octal or hex escape sequences.

@jasonharper then how gperf could understand the LF? The -l doesn't take any value such as the length of each keyword. If I convert my data to hex escape sequences, I will have 4 bytes for a 16-bit keyword, this is not optimal

If you have a 16-bit value, let's say 0x1234 in hexadecimal, you'd have to write it as \x12\x34 in gperf's input file.  It's still a two-byte value, this is just encoding it for input into a normally text-based program.

@jasonharper I am still confused if I do echo -e "\x12\x34\x56\x78" | gperf -l, gperf doesn't know the length of each keyword.

Hi, so CANopen slave stack is there a specific reason you are looking for so much speed? Why not just do an array and bsearch it and call it a day?

@KamilCuk, because I am currently using 90% of my MCU treating 16 PDO at 1Mbps + the SDO requests that arrives. The current implementation using bsearch is inefficient because of all comparisons (pipeline flush).

gperf can "understand" what you are giving it and it has it's own "language". See https://opensource.apple.com/source/gperf/gperf-4/gperf/doc/gperf_5.html . But I was not able to pass (pure) binary to it. I got is printf "%s\n" '"\x12\x34"' '"\x56\x78"' | gperf -l , which also includes zero terminating char on the end of strings, but except for that it works. From the look of the source code https://github.com/yakaz/gperf/blob/master/src/input.cc#L784 it only supports "quoted" or unquoted keywords.
